# Setting pause time via interactive user input

Tags: matlab, video

Before I start with anything, I'd like to apologize for how elementary and basic this question might seem, and my own ignorance.

I've decided to learn Matlab because it seems interesting. Now, I don't have any prior knowledge of programming, and I don't know any other programming languages. I'm most likely young by most of your standards as I'm still in Highschool. While other programming languages have step by step online tutorials (so I've heard), Matlab has nothing except a few videos and the documentation (which I'm struggling to understand and navigate). I want to learn Matlab rather than any other language because apparently that's what I need to help out at my dad's workplace.

Anyway, to the problem. I'm builiding a basic video player, which doesn't play videos like .avi but rather data packages that contain many different frames, .tif files or similar.

This is what I have for the play button (I'm using a pushbutton)

```
%// --- Executes on button press in play.
function play_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
%// hObject    handle to play (see GCBO)
%// eventdata  reserved - to be defined in a future version of MATLAB
%// handles    structure with handles and user data (see GUIDATA)
play = 1;
im_info = imfinfo('./Rat_FDB_MG29_RyR_04_R_image.tif'); %//want to make this a variable that is able to be changed through the input file, maybe through iminfo(inputfile)?
imLength = length(im_info);
if play == 1
    for i=1:imLength
        im = imread('./Rat_FDB_MG29_RyR_04_R_image.tif', 'index', i); %//same as above with the file variable change
        imagesc(im);
        axis equal; 
        axis ij;
        axis off;
        colormap gray;
        pause(.1); %// I want to make it pause(inputinc) so the user can change the frame rate from the gui, but that doesn't work
        drawnow;    
    end
else
end
```

This code was mostly generated from copy and paste and some guess and check. Miraculously it works and a video plays. The functions I understand is the pause function, the `imread` function, and the `iminfo(kinda)`. The problem is I have two `edit-text`s in the GUI, one input determines the frame rate of the video and the other determines the name of the video.

Here is the function for the `edit-text`

```
function increment_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
%// hObject    handle to increment (see GCBO)
%// eventdata  reserved - to be defined in a future version of MATLAB
%// handles    structure with handles and user data (see GUIDATA)

%// Hints: get(hObject,'String') returns contents of increment as text
%//        str2double(get(hObject,'String')) returns contents of increment as a double
inputinc = str2num(get(hObject,'String'));
%//this is the increment in which the frames play, I have to figure out how
%//to get it into the play function
```

In the `play` function there is the `pause` function, which I understand to be the time that passes before the next frame is played. So `pause(.5)` would allow `.5` seconds to pass before playing the next frame. However, when I do `pause(inputinc)` it gives an error and the 2nd frame after the frame does not play. At first I figured it was because the name that comes through the `edit-text` is a string but even after using `str2num` it still gives an error. Is it because the `edit-text` function is lower in the function page than the play pushbutton function?

Here is the full function script if it helps people understand what I'm trying to do.

```
function varargout = untitled(varargin)
%// UNTITLED MATLAB code for untitled.fig
%//      UNTITLED, by itself, creates a new UNTITLED or raises the existing
%//      singleton*.
%//
%//      H = UNTITLED returns the handle to a new UNTITLED or the handle to
%//      the existing singleton*.
%//
%//      UNTITLED('CALLBACK',hObject,eventData,handles,...) calls the local
%//      function named CALLBACK in UNTITLED.M with the given input arguments.
%//
%//      UNTITLED('Property','Value',...) creates a new UNTITLED or raises the
%//      existing singleton*.  Starting from the left, property value pairs are
%//      applied to the GUI before untitled_OpeningFcn gets called.  An
%//      unrecognized property name or invalid value makes property application
%//      stop.  All inputs are passed to untitled_OpeningFcn via varargin.
%//
%//      *See GUI Options on GUIDE's Tools menu.  Choose "GUI allows only one
%//      instance to run (singleton)".
%//
%// See also: GUIDE, GUIDATA, GUIHANDLES

%// Edit the above text to modify the response to help untitled

%// Last Modified by GUIDE v2.5 03-Aug-2015 22:31:53

%// Begin initialization code - DO NOT EDIT
gui_Singleton = 1;
gui_State = struct('gui_Name',       mfilename, ...
                   'gui_Singleton',  gui_Singleton, ...
                   'gui_OpeningFcn', @untitled_OpeningFcn, ...
                   'gui_OutputFcn',  @untitled_OutputFcn, ...
                   'gui_LayoutFcn',  [] , ...
                   'gui_Callback',   []);
if nargin && ischar(varargin{1})
    gui_State.gui_Callback = str2func(varargin{1});
end

if nargout
    [varargout{1:nargout}] = gui_mainfcn(gui_State, varargin{:});
else
    gui_mainfcn(gui_State, varargin{:});
end
%// End initialization code - DO NOT EDIT


%// --- Executes just before untitled is made visible.
function untitled_OpeningFcn(hObject, eventdata, handles, varargin)
%// This function has no output args, see OutputFcn.
%// hObject    handle to figure
%// eventdata  reserved - to be defined in a future version of MATLAB
%// handles    structure with handles and user data (see GUIDATA)
%// varargin   command line arguments to untitled (see VARARGIN)


%// Choose default command line output for untitled
handles.output = hObject;
inputinc = .1

%// Update handles structure
guidata(hObject, handles);

%// UIWAIT makes untitled wait for user response (see UIRESUME)
%// uiwait(handles.figure1);


%// --- Outputs from this function are returned to the command line.
function varargout = untitled_OutputFcn(hObject, eventdata, handles) 
%// varargout  cell array for returning output args (see VARARGOUT);
%// hObject    handle to figure
%// eventdata  reserved - to be defined in a future version of MATLAB
%// handles    structure with handles and user data (see GUIDATA)

%// Get default command line output from handles structure
varargout{1} = handles.output;


%//my functions start here, I'm a beginner programmer that got his hands on
%//matlab through his dad's workplace access (dad doesn't use matlab, just has
%//access to it)
%//I don't know how to use anything besides matlab
%//i don't know how to use matlab
%//help pleaes
%//I'm trying to make a basic gui that plays frames except I have no idea how
%//the format works and stuff

%// --- Executes on button press in play.
function play_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
%// hObject    handle to play (see GCBO)
%// eventdata  reserved - to be defined in a future version of MATLAB
%// handles    structure with handles and user data (see GUIDATA)
play = 1;
im_info = imfinfo('./Rat_FDB_MG29_RyR_04_R_image.tif'); %want to make this a variable that is able to be changed through the input file, maybe through iminfo(inputfile)?
imLength = length(im_info);
play = inputdlg('
if play == 1
    for i=1:imLength
        im = imread('./Rat_FDB_MG29_RyR_04_R_image.tif', 'index', i); %same as above with the file variable change
        imagesc(im);
        axis equal; axis ij;axis off;
        colormap gray;
        pause(.1); % I want to make it pause(inputinc) so the user can change the frame rate from the gui, but that doesn't work
        drawnow;    
    end
else
end
%// plays, but play/pause function is invalid, also, unable to manipulate
%// file name 


%// --- Executes on button press in pause.
function pause_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
%// hObject    handle to pause (see GCBO)
%// eventdata  reserved - to be defined in a future version of MATLAB
%// handles    structure with handles and user data (see GUIDATA)
play = 0
%//pauses the video, not as important but I can't get it to work either

%// --- Executes on button press in exit.
function exit_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
%// hObject    handle to exit (see GCBO)
%// eventdata  reserved - to be defined in a future version of MATLAB
%// handles    structure with handles and user data (see GUIDATA)
exit = questdlg('Are you sure you want to quit?','Exit Confirmation','Yes','No','No');
switch exit
    case 'Yes'
        close(untitled)
    case 'No'
end 
%//exist function, the only thing that works so far as intended :D


function increment_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
%// hObject    handle to increment (see GCBO)
%// eventdata  reserved - to be defined in a future version of MATLAB
%// handles    structure with handles and user data (see GUIDATA)

%// Hints: get(hObject,'String') returns contents of increment as text
%//        str2double(get(hObject,'String')) returns contents of increment as a double
inputinc = str2num(get(hObject,'String'));
%//this is the increment in which the frames play, I have to figure out how
%//to get it into the play function
%// I can't get pause(inputinc) to work,


%// --- Executes during object creation, after setting all properties.
function increment_CreateFcn(hObject, eventdata, handles)
%// hObject    handle to increment (see GCBO)
%// eventdata  reserved - to be defined in a future version of MATLAB
%// handles    empty - handles not created until after all CreateFcns called

%// Hint: edit controls usually have a white background on Windows.
%//       See ISPC and COMPUTER.
if ispc && isequal(get(hObject,'BackgroundColor'), get(0,'defaultUicontrolBackgroundColor'))
    set(hObject,'BackgroundColor','white');
end
%//no idea what this is


function file_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
%// hObject    handle to file (see GCBO)
%// eventdata  reserved - to be defined in a future version of MATLAB
%// handles    structure with handles and user data (see GUIDATA)

%// Hints: get(hObject,'String') returns contents of file as text
%//        str2double(get(hObject,'String')) returns contents of file as a double
inputfile = get(hObject,'String');
%// user inputs file name here 
%// i have to figure out how to get it inside the play function


%// --- Executes during object creation, after setting all properties.
function file_CreateFcn(hObject, eventdata, handles)
%// hObject    handle to file (see GCBO)
%// eventdata  reserved - to be defined in a future version of MATLAB
%// handles    empty - handles not created until after all CreateFcns called

%// Hint: edit controls usually have a white background on Windows.
%//       See ISPC and COMPUTER.
if ispc && isequal(get(hObject,'BackgroundColor'), get(0,'defaultUicontrolBackgroundColor'))
    set(hObject,'BackgroundColor','white');
end
%//no idea what this is
```

I'm building this more for practice than for anything else. Some guy in my dad's workplace told me I should to a project to help improve. I'm hoping one day I could be of use instead of a burden.

Also I want to be able to figure out how to change the file from the gui using another `edit-text` but I haven't gotten to that part yet. The pause button is another issue and I'm trying to figure out a system that pauses the video, also, another problem I discovered was that if I press play it starts the video over, is there a way to log the frame of the video and then start from there instead?

Thanks for the help everyone, it's greatly appreciated by a very beginner programmer.

Comment: You get error because the variables you use in one function are out of scope in another (they are unknown). A useful read until an answer comes up : [Share Data Among Callbacks](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/creating_guis/share-data-among-callbacks.html)

Answer (score 0):

You will need to do some reading about `scope` of variable to understand what went wrong in your code. I encourage you to start with:

[Share Data Among Callbacks](http://mathworks.com/help/matlab/creating_guis/share-data-among-callbacks.html)

[Check Variable Scope](http://mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/check-variable-scope-in-editor.html)

In simple terms, you have to see the different functions in your code as *independant*. One function use it's own variables but doesn't know about the variables of the other functions. There are different ways to make these functions communicates variables to each other (the most common way is by sending the desired variable in the input parameters of the functions, but the link above will show you some other ways).

---

From you gui code, I deduct that you have two text boxes named `increment` and `file`. The first thing I would do is suggest to rename these with a kind of identifier which let you know what type of object they are (textbox field). For example I would use `txtIncrement` and `txtFile`, but that part is totally up to you.

To get the content of one of these text box, you call the `get` method and you pass the handle of the object from which you want information. You did it already in the callback function:

```
inputfile = get(hObject,'String');
```

In there, `hObject` was the handle of the text box. Unfortunately, the variable `inputfile` disappear as soon as the function finishes, so it is not available for the other functions. You could save the variable `inputfile` using `setappdata` or `guidata` to make it available, but in simple cases like yours, you can directly read the text box content from the function which will use it. All you need is the **handle** of the text box, but you have it too: it is in the structure named `handles` (the third parameters in your functions).

So directly in your main "play" function:

```
function play_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)

%// retrieve all the information we need from the GUI before going further
inputfile =         get( handles.file      ,'String') ;  %// notice the handle of the "file" textbox
inputinc  = str2num(get( handles.increment ,'String')) ; %// notice the handle of the "increment " textbox

%// from now on, in this function, the variables "inputfile" and "inputinc" are known so you can use:
play = 1;
im_info = iminfo(inputfile);
%//
%// and later on in the code, you can also use:
pause(inputinc) ;
```

Note that if you retrieve the text box content this way from the main playing function, you can remove the bits of code in the text box callbacks.